# How do styles split for mobile and desktop page in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to split styles by different .css files in Blazor to only one of them includes in header depending device's page. But I can know which type of device is asked my page only on my .razor page:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        isMobile = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isMobile");
        await generateCaptcha();
    }
}
```

Can I include styles from my razor page to header? Or what other methods can I use for resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling js from your component, you can just add, change or remove any dom element from there. Another option for you may be to dynamically change the CSS content whit `@import`

```
@import 'sm.css' screen and (max-width: 768px);
@import 'md.css' screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 769px);
@import 'lg.css' screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 993px);
@import 'xl.css' screen and (max-width: 1336px) and (min-width: 1025px);
/*and many other options - and only screen, and (orientation: landscape)*/
```